# SQL Server Drivers for PHP 5.3.13

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I have been trying to install SQL Server drivers for my wamp server 32 bit ( php ver 5.3.13 ) and I downloaded the drivers from Microsoft download site I copied them to ext folder and changed the php.ini file but I'm still getting errors. Could you please give me a full installation manual I really need to sort this out and start developing some codes on this.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Comment: I tried IIS but when I try to run mssql command on it, it doesnt works I am using this script to connect 

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

do you think i need to use something else

Comment: Maybe this question could help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963551/sql-server-instead-of-mysql-in-wamp

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use PDO this would solve your issues? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

EDIT:

Download SQL driver for PHP - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: hi kyle I don't have the php_pdo.dll in my extension folder where can I download it